# Google App Engine Cloud Build Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Let me explain my current situation, I'm trying to host a Wordpress in a Flexible App Engine environment, the problem is that I have activated CloudBuild triggers for a CI / CD, but at the time of deploying, CloudBuild return me the following error:

> Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response : [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

I have searched for this error and all that I have found is that CloudBuild exceeded the build time but, it is configured for 1800 seconds in the cloudbuild.yaml file and running the `gcloud config set app / cloud_build_timeout` command but the error persists
I think the problem is when CloudBuild is trying to push the image to container registry because if I try to launch a new version of App Engine locally with the `gcloud app deploy` command it worked correctly, previously all the deploys work correctly, the only change I made was to the base image, I was using alpine as a base image, I tried to use the official images of ubuntu or php-fpm, but neither work, I thought maybe it was a problem with the size of the image but the strangest thing is that the deploys don't have a 100% failure rate, if run again a deploy that has failed this may work, I would like to know if someone else has experienced this error in order to know how to resolve it

Comment: Hi, Have you tried doing your builds using the `gcloud builds submit` with the `--timeout` flag? Also use the `--verbosity="debug"` tag to get more information about what is failing with the deployments. If you are using `gcloud app deploy` please consider to use the `--verbosity="debug"` to make a better diagnosis of the issue

Answer (score 0):

You’re right, the **DEADLINE_EXCEEDED** error is typically raised if the request did not complete in the time allocated. With this error, the server may or may not execute the operation requested.

Since **Flexible Environment** doesn't impose a 60 second request deadline *(like the Standard Environment does)*, it’s important to ensure that all calls to external services specify a timeout in order to avoid requests hanging indefinitely.

As GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/flexible-for-standard-users#maximum_request_timeout) mentions:

> Application developers can implement their own **servlet filter** to kill
>   requests that take longer than 60 seconds in the flexible environment.
>   It is important to handle clean up correctly when killing a request
>   thread, so that the application is not left in an inconsistent state.

Another **workaround** would be to try breaking the request that you're making into **several smaller requests**.

In addition, you can take a look into [**app caching**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#opcache). Caching PHP intermediate code will significantly improve your application's response time.

Comment: Hi -- Your answer is a bit irrelevant, I'm afraid. We are not talking about the 60-second limitation on GAE... We are talking about Cloud Build here.